# Reputations recalculations

Tags: support, reputation

If I go to https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation the amount computed at the end differs from the amount I see. Before, there was a way to trigger a recalculation, but I do not know if this is possible any longer. Is there a way to fix/explain the discrepancy?

Comment: How discrepant?

Comment: 22. Which is not much but it is odder (as I was actually expecting a discrepancy of 2).

Comment: OK. It seems fixed now. Certainly this did not happen as suggested [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/871/requests-to-remove-community-wiki#comment4044_871).

Comment: I actually recall something similar happening before (to me). But Knowing that recalc may take several hours, I just waited it to be correct again.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. The comment I just linked to indicates there should be no wait, which suggests that either there is a glitch or there is something else going on now.

Comment: My dull experience with with writing software says, there's always a glitch.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: the intertubes was just very, very full at that moment so it took some time for those two digits to arrive. You are lucky the discrepency wasn't 2222 rep: that would've likely taken twice as long to fix. `:-)`